# Fill form field with ajax request not working in other file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize first for this question. I tried to fill data in sale_price section but it still no work.

R1. My sale4.php is okay. I tried it with this url and it has returns as I need.

sale4.php?q=Samsung%20Galaxy%20S4

R2. My test.php is okay. IT returned/filled with obtained value from sale4.php

But in my cash.php file it is working well. Can anyone tell what is my wrong?
Screen shot:
[image]
[image]
Explain:

- test.php: send get request to sale4.php
- sale4.php return sale price with $_GET var.
- cash.php the applied file to obtain as test.php. My file are bellow-

// sale4.php

```
<?php
 include('../_db/_con.php');
    $m=$_GET['q'];

    $que="SELECT `purchase_list`.`sale_price` , `purchase_list`.`pur_id`
FROM  `purchase_list` 
JOIN  `item_info` ON  `purchase_list`.`item_id` =  `item_info`.`item_id`

WHERE  `purchase_list`.`sale_price` <>0 AND `item_info`.`item_name` =  '$m'";

        $result = $mysqli->query($que);
        $y=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        echo $y['0'];

include('../_db/con_.php');
 ?>
```

//test.php

```
<html><head><title>hello</title></head><body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
function sale_price(itemed)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.get("sale4.php?q="+itemed,function(data,status)
        {
        $("#sale").val(data);
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
}
</script>
<input onChange="sale_price(this.value)" value="Mobile battery">
  <input id="sale" value="<?php
  $msg='fdf'; print $msg; ?>">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

// cash.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Epos</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/epos/css/jquery-ui.css" />


<style type="text/css">

#body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
#main{
    font-size: 40px;
    color:#039;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
#bottom{
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#039;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
#menuWrapper {
width:1000px; /* Menu width */
height:35px;
padding-left:14px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 10px; /* Menu border roundedness */
}
.menu {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
height:35px;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.menu li:hover li a {
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}
.menu li.top {display:block; float:left;}

.menu li a.top_link {
display:block;
float:left;
height:35px;
line-height:34px;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif;
font-size:16px; /* Tama�o de la fuente */
font-weight:bold;
padding:0 0 0 12px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.menu li a.top_link span {
float:left;
display:block;
padding:0 24px 0 12px;
height:35px;
width:146px;
}

.menu li a.top_link:hover, .menu li:hover > a.top_link {color:#000; }
.menu li:hover {position:relative; z-index:2;}
.menu ul
{position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.menu li:hover ul.sub {
left:0;
top:35px;
background:#CBE4E4; /* Submenu background color */
padding:3px;
color:#000;
white-space:nowrap;
width:200px;
height:auto;
z-index:3;
}

.menu li:hover ul.sub li a{
display:block;
height:30px;
width:200px;
line-height:30px;
text-indent:5px;
color:#000;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:600;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li:hover ul.sub li a:hover {
background: #0779F8; /* Background Color on mouseover */
color:#fff;
}
table{
margin:0 auto;
}
.h1{
font-size:72px;;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
  <center>
  <span class="h1">EPOS</span>
  </center>
<div id="menuWrapper">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="top">
<a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php"><span class="top">Epos</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php">Admin setup</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/?q=group-master">Company setup</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<li class="top">
<a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php"><span class="top">Master</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php">User master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/?q=group-master">Group master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/units.php">Unit master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/categories.php">Category master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/item.php">Item master</a></li>
</ul>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/?go=rent"><span class="top">Market</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/cash.php">Cash sale</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/credit.php">Credit sale</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/cash-ps.php">Cash purchase</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/credit-ps.php">Credit purchase</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/cash-ps2.php">Cash purchase2</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/credit-ps2.php">Credit purchase2</a></li>
</ul>
<span>&nbsp;</span></li>
<li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/?go=account"><span class="top">Account</span></a>
<span>&nbsp;</span></li>
<li class="top"><a class="top_link"  href="?go=reports"><span class="top">Reports</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div></header>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
function sale_price(itemed)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.get("sale4.php?q="+itemed,function(data,status)
        {
        $("#sale").val(data);
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
}
</script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var items = ["Motorola Razr HD",
    "iPhone 4",
    "Samsung Galaxy S3",
    "Motorola Razr HD",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Samsung Galaxy S4",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Samsung Galaxy S4",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Sony Xperia S",
    "Walton Mobile",
    "Mobile",
        ""
    ];
    $( "#item" ).autocomplete({
      source: items
    });
    var dates = [
    "",
    "20/7/2013"
    ];
    $( "#day" ).autocomplete({
      source: dates
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .y2
  {
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  }
  .scope
  {
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  padding:4px;
  }
  .y1
  {
  width:25px;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  }
  .y21
  {
  width:55px;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  }
  #txt
  {
  width:200px;
  height:25px;
  }
  #input{
  background-color:#666666;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  border:#000 1px solid;
  padding:2px;
  font-weight:600;
  }
  td
  {
  padding:3px;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
  th
  {
  width:300px;
  }
  .ordel
  {
  width:300px;
  }
  </style>
  <div id="hello"></div>
  <form action="cash.php" method="post" name="users">
<table width="400" border="0" class="ui-widget">
    <tr>    
        <th class="col">Date</th>
        <th class="col">Customer</th>       
        <th class="col">Note</th>
        <th class="col">Item</th>
        <th class="col">Quantity</th>
        <th class="col">Vat(%)</th>
    </tr><input name="form" value="usr" type="hidden">
        <tr>
    <td><input size="10" name="date" id="day" value="20/7/2013" type="text"></td>

    <td><input size="20" name="customer" id="customer" value="" type="text"></td>

        <td><textarea id="txt" name="note" id="info"></textarea></td>

    <td><input onChange="sale_price(this.value)" size="20" name="item_name" id="item" value="" type="text"></td>

    <td><input size="10" name="qty" id="qty" value="" type="text"></td>

    <td><input name="vat" size="5" id="vat" value="" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <th align="left" colspan="3">Sale Price:
    <input id="salep" name="sale" size="5" value="" type="text">
    Profit:
    <input disabled="disabled" name="price" size="5" value="" type="text"></th><th align="left" colspan="5">
    <input name="add" value="Add new" id="input" type="submit"> <input name="go" size="4" value="" placeholder="10" id="lab" type="text">
    <input name="goto" value="Go to S.N." id="input" type="submit">
    <input value="Delete" name="delete" id="input" type="submit"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>

        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">#</th>        
        <th style="width:145px;" class="scope">Date</th>
        <th style="width:225px;" class="scope">Customer</th>        
        <th style="width:645px;" class="scope">Note</th>
        <th style="width:205px;" class="scope">Item</th>
        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">Sale(each)</th>
        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">Bye(each)</th>
        <th style="width:35px;" class="scope">Quantity</th>
        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">Vat</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">1</td>
                <td class="y21">18 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope"></td>
                <td class="y2"><i></i></td>
                <td class="y2">Mobile</td>
                <td class="y2">11111111</td>
                <td class="y2">444444</td>
                <td class="y2">4 Taka</td>
                <td class="y2">10%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">2</td>
                <td class="y21">20 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Shiam</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>asdf</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Huawei Ascend G330</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">78</td>
                <td class="y2">8 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">10%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">3</td>
                <td class="y21">20 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Shiam</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>asdf</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Huawei Ascend G330</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">78</td>
                <td class="y2">8 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">10%</td>
            </tr></table>


    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell what Error Console giving ? and please add jquery to case.php

Comment: The test.php file is working well(Filled form value with ajax  get request) But same code is not working another file(cash.php). Can you explain, Why?

Comment: I have added <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> in cash.php but still no work.

Comment: Can you tell what Errors Javascript Console giving ? If you using Chrome you can find out by "F12" key

Comment: Javascript Console giving no errors. You can try this codes on your browser. As sale4.php you can make assoc array with $_GET to response with get variable.

Comment: I have edited script sources for your easy.

Comment: Just add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> . I think it'll be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery 1.10.1 and jquery UI for autocomplete 1.10.3

Comment: I`ve changed.But no new result.

Comment: The error is not on javascript console. I haven't got sale price from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need as so.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Epos</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/epos/css/jquery-ui.css" />


<style type="text/css">

#body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
#main{
    font-size: 40px;
    color:#039;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
#bottom{
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#039;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
#menuWrapper {
width:1000px; /* Menu width */
height:35px;
padding-left:14px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 10px; /* Menu border roundedness */
}
.menu {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
height:35px;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.menu li:hover li a {
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}
.menu li.top {display:block; float:left;}

.menu li a.top_link {
display:block;
float:left;
height:35px;
line-height:34px;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif;
font-size:16px; /* Tama�o de la fuente */
font-weight:bold;
padding:0 0 0 12px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.menu li a.top_link span {
float:left;
display:block;
padding:0 24px 0 12px;
height:35px;
width:146px;
}

.menu li a.top_link:hover, .menu li:hover > a.top_link {color:#000; }
.menu li:hover {position:relative; z-index:2;}
.menu ul
{position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.menu li:hover ul.sub {
left:0;
top:35px;
background:#CBE4E4; /* Submenu background color */
padding:3px;
color:#000;
white-space:nowrap;
width:200px;
height:auto;
z-index:3;
}

.menu li:hover ul.sub li a{
display:block;
height:30px;
width:200px;
line-height:30px;
text-indent:5px;
color:#000;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:600;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li:hover ul.sub li a:hover {
background: #0779F8; /* Background Color on mouseover */
color:#fff;
}
table{
margin:0 auto;
}
.h1{
font-size:72px;;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
  <center>
  <span class="h1">EPOS</span>
  </center>
<div id="menuWrapper">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="top">
<a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php"><span class="top">Epos</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php">Admin setup</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/?q=group-master">Company setup</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<li class="top">
<a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php"><span class="top">Master</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/user.php">User master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/?q=group-master">Group master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/units.php">Unit master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/categories.php">Category master</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/master/item.php">Item master</a></li>
</ul>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/?go=rent"><span class="top">Market</span></a>
<ul class="sub">
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/cash.php">Cash sale</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/credit.php">Credit sale</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/cash-ps.php">Cash purchase</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/credit-ps.php">Credit purchase</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/cash-ps2.php">Cash purchase2</a></li>
<li class="top"><a href="http://localhost/epos/market/credit-ps2.php">Credit purchase2</a></li>
</ul>
<span>&nbsp;</span></li>
<li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="http://localhost/epos/?go=account"><span class="top">Account</span></a>
<span>&nbsp;</span></li>
<li class="top"><a class="top_link"  href="?go=reports"><span class="top">Reports</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div></header>


    <script src="http://localhost/epos/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/epos/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
function checkform() 
{   var q1 = parseInt(document.form.qty.value);
    var q2 = parseInt(document.form.q.value);
if(q1 > q2) 
{
    alert("Maximum available quantity is "+q2);
    return false;
}
else
{
    document.form.submit();
}
}

function sale_price(itemed)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.get("sale4.php?q="+itemed,function(data,status)
        {
        var prcS = data.split("|");
        var prc = prcS[0];
        document.getElementById("sale").value=prc;
        var prc2 = prcS[1];
        document.getElementById("qt").innerHTML=prc2;
        });
    });
}

function myformat(x) {
    var partz = x.toString();
    var parts = partz.split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

function calculated()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var prc = parseInt(document.getElementById("sale").value);

        var vatQ = document.getElementById("vat").value;
        var vatzz =vatQ*prc;
        var vat= vatzz/100;
        var prc1=parseInt(vat)+parseInt(prc);
        var quan = document.getElementById("qty").value;

        var inp = parseInt(quan)*prc1;
        var vals= parseInt(inp);
        var x1 = myformat(vals);
        var parts1 = inp.toString();
        var parts = parts1.split('.');
        var x2 = parts[1] ? "." + myformat(parts[1]) : "";
        var profits = x1+x2;
         var elem = document.getElementById("profit");
        if(inp){
        elem.setAttribute("style","font-family: Tahoma; background-color: #ccc; font-weight: bold; color:#000;");
        $("#profit").val(profits);
        }else{
        elem.setAttribute("style","font-family: Courier; background-color: red; text-decoration: blink; color:#fff;");
        alert("Please enter info");
        $("#profit").val("0");
        }
        //document.getElementById("profit").value=profits;
        //alert(profits);

    });
}
</script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var items = ["Samsung Galaxy S4",
    "Motorola Razr HD",
    "iPhone 4",
    "Samsung Galaxy S3",
    "Motorola Razr HD",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Samsung Galaxy S4",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Samsung Galaxy S4",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Mobile equipment",
    "Sony Xperia S",
    "Walton Mobile",
    "Mobile",
        ""
    ];
    $( "#item" ).autocomplete({
      source: items
    });
    var dates = [
    "",
    "22/7/2013"
    ];
    $( "#day" ).autocomplete({
      source: dates
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .y2
  {
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  }
  .scope
  {
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  padding:4px;
  }
  .y1
  {
  width:25px;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  }
  .y21
  {
  width:55px;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  }
  #txt
  {
  width:200px;
  height:25px;
  }
  #txt:hover{
  background-color:#999999;
  border:#666666 1px solid;
  padding:5px;
  }
  #input{
  background-color:#666666;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  border:#000 1px solid;
  padding:2px;
  font-weight:600;
  }
  td
  {
  padding:3px;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
  th
  {
  width:300px;
  }
  .ordel
  {
  width:300px;
  }
  </style>
  <div id="hello"></div>
  <form action="cash.php" method="post" name="form">
<table width="400" border="0" class="ui-widget">
    <tr>    
        <th class="col">Date</th>
        <th class="col">Customer</th>       
        <th class="col">Note</th>
        <th class="col">Item</th>
        <th class="col">Quantity</th>
        <th class="col">Vat(%)</th>
    </tr><input name="form" value="usr" type="hidden">
        <tr>
    <td><input size="10" name="date" id="day" value="22/7/2013" type="text"></td>

    <td><input size="20" name="customer" id="customer" value="" type="text"></td>

        <td><textarea onFocus="if(this.value=='n/a'){this.value=''}" id="txt" name="note" id="info">n/a</textarea></td>

    <td><input onChange="sale_price(this.value)" size="20" name="item_name" id="item" value="" type="text"></td>

    <td id="qt">

    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="q" id="q">

    <input size="10" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" type="text"></td>

    <td><input onChange="" name="vat" size="5" id="vat" value="5" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <th align="left" colspan="3">Price(each):
    <input id="sale" name="sale" size="6" value="" type="text">
    Total(+Vat):
    <input name="price" disabled="disabled" id="profit" size="6" value="" type="text">
    &nbsp;<input id="input" type="button" onClick="calculated()" value="Calculate"></th><th align="left" colspan="5">
    <input onClick="return checkform()" name="add" value="Add new" id="input" type="submit">    <input name="go" size="4" value="" placeholder="10" id="lab" type="text">
    <input name="goto" value="Go to S.N." id="input" type="submit">
    <input value="Delete" name="delete" id="input" type="submit"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>

        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">#</th>        
        <th style="width:145px;" class="scope">Date</th>
        <th style="width:225px;" class="scope">Customer</th>        
        <th style="width:645px;" class="scope">Note</th>
        <th style="width:205px;" class="scope">Item</th>
        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">Sale(each)</th>
        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">Bye(each)</th>
        <th style="width:35px;" class="scope">Quantity</th>
        <th style="width:25px;" class="scope">Vat</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">1</td>
                <td class="y21">18 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope"></td>
                <td class="y2"><i></i></td>
                <td class="y2">Mobile</td>
                <td class="y2">11111111</td>
                <td class="y2">444444</td>
                <td class="y2">4 Taka</td>
                <td class="y2">10%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">2</td>
                <td class="y21">20 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Shiam</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>asdf</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Huawei Ascend G330</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">78</td>
                <td class="y2">8 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">10%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">3</td>
                <td class="y21">20 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Shiam</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>asdf</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Huawei Ascend G330</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">78</td>
                <td class="y2">8 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">10%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">4</td>
                <td class="y21">20 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">jonson</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>n/a</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Motorola Razr HD</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">6000</td>
                <td class="y2">2 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">12%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">17</td>
                <td class="y21">22 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Shiamss</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>dsadasd</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Motorola Razr HD</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">8000</td>
                <td class="y2">100 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">5%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">18</td>
                <td class="y21">22 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Mister Don</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>He is a mangow people.</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Mobile equipment</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">1222</td>
                <td class="y2">30 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">5%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">19</td>
                <td class="y21">22 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Doen</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>nothing</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Sony Xperia S</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">8000</td>
                <td class="y2">5 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">2%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">20</td>
                <td class="y21">22 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Northern</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>no need to do.</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Sony Xperia S</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">8000</td>
                <td class="y2">4 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">5%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">21</td>
                <td class="y21">22 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Sael</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>win to do</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Sony Xperia S</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">4000</td>
                <td class="y2">5 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">5%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="y1">22</td>
                <td class="y21">22 July 2013</td>
                <td class="scope">Sael</td>
                <td class="y2"><i>win to do</i></td>
                <td class="y2">Sony Xperia S</td>
                <td class="y2">0</td>
                <td class="y2">4000</td>
                <td class="y2">5 piece</td>
                <td class="y2">5%</td>
            </tr></table>


    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```